# How to display the current mapping for keyboard shortcuts in realtime?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, keybindings

Is there an app / script which will listen for keyboard events and display the action that is triggered?

I use Better Touch Tool, and want to run a script on <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but I got the message:

> The key combination "Command + F1" can't be used because it's already used by a system-wide keyboard shortcut. (If you really want to use this key combination, most shortcuts can be changed in the Keyboard & Mouse panel in System Preferences.)

I couldn't find the triggered action until I did a text search on http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1343, and now I'm curious!

In Sublime Text, it's possible to open Sublime's python terminal and `sublime.log_commands(True)` to log commands triggered as the keys are pressed… is there something similar for system wide key events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This program shows all keyboard shortcuts that use the ⌘ (command) key, just by pressing and holding command.
http://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/

It does not show shortcuts that do not include command, but is quick and easy to use.

Comment: oops.. i didn't select an answer! points for first - all the suggestions here look good.

Answer (score 3):

I use [KeyCue](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/). It's similar to [@avv](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205261/123620)'s recommendation but more customisable.

Answer (score 2):

Woohoo! After some more looking, I've found https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/ which does everything I want! Please let me know if there's a lighter-weight alternative…

---

To see keyboard events using Karabiner:

- open the app
- enable Karabiner under System Prefs > Accessibility
- (maybe restart the AX notifier)
- click the icon in the menu bar (near the time)
- select **Launch EventViewer**

The event viewer will show a log of events like:

```
eventType:FlagsChanged    code:0x37       name:Command_L       flags:Cmd                                misc:KeyCode::COMMAND_L  characters:    
eventType:FlagsChanged    code:0x37       name:Command_L       flags:                                   misc:KeyCode::COMMAND_L  characters:    
eventType:SysKeyDown      code:0x1        name:                flags:                                   misc:ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN
eventType:SysKeyUp        code:0x1        name:                flags:                                   misc:ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_DOWN
eventType:SysKeyDown      code:0x0        name:                flags:                                   misc:ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP
eventType:SysKeyUp        code:0x0        name:                flags:                                   misc:ConsumerKeyCode::VOLUME_UP
```

(scroll right to see the flags)

It may be useful to click the Preferences tab in EventViewer to 'always show on top' and uncheck 'hide ignorable events'.

Comment: How do you show the bounded key through karabiner?

Comment: @AgafadaEm - I've added instructions for you, hope that helps!