# How can I produce a list of all assigned keyboard shortcuts OR test if a combo is already assigned in Big Sur without using additional software?

Tags: keyboard, big-sur, shortcut

If it's possible, I would like to either i) produce a list of assigned keyboard shortcuts for macOS Big Sur and installed (or running) applications or ii) quickly identify/test if a keyboard combo is available to assign without conflicting (the Keyboard > Shortcuts control panel doesn't always work for this).

Previous posts have asked *similar* questions, but the solutions offered are usually to rely on buying third-party software or installing a cheatsheet application.

What I would like to know is if there is a way for macOS to do these itself, e.g. via Terminal or AppleScript?

Comment: Arguably, if third-party software can do it, then you could access the same APIs using a scripting language. It would probably be quite complex, and not something you could do in a few lines.

Comment: Perhaps you will have [better luck than Peter](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342362/5472) in demonstrating with edits [your desired solution is not already covered here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/145582/5472)

Comment: @bmike I had not seen Peter's question when searching before posting. It appears to ask for the same kind of answer/solution I am looking for, which seems unlikely based on the responses provided (the closest and only current solution I've found seems to be the KeyCue application). I'm happy for my question to be closed as a duplicate of Peter's.