# How can I make a keyboard shortcut to strikethrough text in the Notes app?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, menu-bar, notes.app

Since Apple decided to give us shortcuts for all the text options except strikethrough, how can we do this with one keyboard stroke?

I saw some other solutions, but I want my <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> shortcut back!!

[image: keyboardShortcuts]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It doesn't need any 3rd party solution, you can do this natively.

System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts.

Click the + sign, select the Notes app [or all apps], the name of the menu command & add the key command of your choice.
BTW, the native functionality doesn't care where in the menu hierarchy it is, it will find it anyway. The only time you ever need to specify is if there are two identically-named functions in different menus in which case you can force a specific menu by `menu name->sub menu->function` syntax

[image]

Comment: If the keyboard shortcut you choose is already in use, this method will silently override it. Is there a way of finding out if this has happened, and/or a way of listing all shortcuts already in use by the chosen app?

Comment: Cheatsheet - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145582/how-to-display-the-current-mapping-for-keyboard-shortcuts-in-realtime?rq=1

Comment: Wow, I learned something!!! You are a hero of the first order.

Comment: Thanks you so much, this was so annoying, and now I can improve ANY application with shortcuts. Incredible.

Comment: Just FYI, I tried this in Ventura (13.0.1) and just typing "Strikethrough" didn't work. I did have to specify "Format->Font->Strikethrough" for the Menu Title in the shortcut config.

Comment: @the-nick-wilson - Interesting. I can't test yet because we don't have anything on Ventura. I never jump for the early updates ;)

Answer (score -1):

I discovered that I can use the [Better Touch Tool app](https://folivora.ai/) to do this super easily!

I added the Notes app specifically and made a `Trigger Menubar Menu-item` shortcut with the text `Format;Font;Strikethrough` that works on Mac OS 11.2.1 that I'm on now.

Works like a charm! It's like they never removed it!

[image]